# VideoJs formatTime is undefined

Tags: video.js

I'm using [videojs](https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/video.html) and want to use the function as per docs `formatTime`, but I get as result **undefined**

I don't use npm package of videojs, instead, I have referenced the minified version 7.6.5 direct in my code.

Is there any extra file I should reference in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a method on `videojs`, not the player instance:

```
videojs.formatTime(100);
> "1:40"
```